Could not spawn process for application - STRAPi - Phusion Passenger Cpanel
I have created a build for my strapi app and tried to deploy it in cpanel with phusion passenger but I keep on getting error
[ E 2024-07-22 12:16:11.1414 209624/T1a age/Cor/App/Implementation.cpp:221 ]: Could not spawn process for application /home/username/public_html/admin.xxx.com: The application process exited prematurely.


app.js
const strapi = require('@strapi/strapi');
strapi({ dir: './dist' }).start();

